# Flutter - Notifications permission not requested

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm making a Flutter app using Firebase Messaging.

I want the user to be requested if he allows notifications when app launches for the first time, before accessing the app.

Following the documentation, here's my function :

```
Future requestPermission() async {
    FirebaseMessaging messaging = await FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: true,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      print('User authorized notifications');
    } else if (settings.authorizationStatus ==
        AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
      print('User authorized notifications provisionnal');
    } else {
      print('User declined notifications');
    }
  }
```

I call it in main.dart inside initState :

```
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    requestPermission();
  }
```

The problem is whenever I uninstall the app and run it again, it doesn't ask for permissions and print `User declined notifications` when the app launches.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you experience it on iOS or Android or both?

Comment: I'm running the app on my physical Android device, so I don't know about iOS...

Comment: And the value is `AuthorizationStatus.denied`? What happens if you try to call `requestPermission` not from the `initState`, but later?

Comment: Yes the status is denied. I tried to call ```requestPermission``` outside the ```initState``` (but still in the main function) and got the same result.

Comment: Normally it should ask if you completely remove the app. It is strange. Sometimes, but mainly with iOS I need to restart the phone to clear some caches.

Comment: Yes, my guess is that I might have denied the permission and it saved this response since then, even if I uninstall the app. You're right it should clear caches. I really don't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Change compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 33 it will work.

This is because from version 13.0.0:

> firebase_messaging now includes this permission: Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS in its AndroidManifest.xml file
> which requires updating your android/app/build.gradle to target API
> level 33.

You can see that in the changelog of the version 13.0.0 of the package https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/changelog

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).